# How to run javascript snippets in firefox/chrome from a script

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to learn javascript. Coming from a python/R background I find it really useful for learning purposes to be able to write code in a script in Rstudio/pyCharm   which I can then execute in a interpreter by highlighting specific lines of code and then pressing a ctrl+enter or some other keyboard shortcut.

The console available on firefox/chrome seems incredibly rich and useful for learning / testing specific pieces of code but I find it quite limiting that I can't store each line in a script with comments/notes to myself.

Is there a way to run lines of javascript in firefox/chrome like pycharm & rstudio can  with their respective interpreters  or how is it usually recommend for people to learn the language in an efficient manner ?

Comment: You can use an external service like https://jsfiddle.net/ ....BTW, your question is off-topic.

Comment: You can also use Firefox's Scratchpad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) which is a javascript runtime using v8 (powering the chrome console)
You can get an REPL similar to Python.

You cannot, however use it to modify the DOM or access the window. In such case, using an online IDE like jsfiddle or codepen might be a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Reading further it appears that (for testing purposes) you can emulate certain aspects of the browser as well in node.js using `jsdom`.

Comment: @CroGo, Yeah, but this will be different from actual browser implementation. Also, you cannot probably use window.alert() window.open() click mouseover listeners etc within the node term.